# Define small caps globally in expex

Tags: fonts, linguistics, expex

A hopefully easy question for `expex`.  Is there a way to globally define a particular line to always print in small caps, similar to how `everyglb=\bf` prints everything on `\glb` as bold face? 
I couldn't figure it out myself, but according to p.37 from the documentation (5.0) I assume I have to define a hook to use with `\everyglb`, for example, that would insert `\textsc{}` around each item on `\glb`.  Now the question is how do I do that?

(If this is standard LaTeX functionality, not specific to `expex` I'd appreciate someone pointing me to where I can read up on it.)

Comment: `\everyglb=\scshape`  perhaps? (untested)

Comment: Yep, that does it!  Thanks @ChristianHupfer!  (Glad it _was_ that easy ...)

Comment: There's basically always the possibility of using the declarative versions like `\bfseries` or `\scshape` to make a constant change of font style, while `\textbf{...}` or `\textsc{...}` limit the effect to just this `{...}` group. Since `expex` uses tabular environments in the background, the effect of a `\bfseries` or `\scshape` is limited to the table cell (which is a group). You can try `\ttfamily` or `\itshape` as well, if needed

Comment: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!

Comment: @jan, you clearly got your question answered, but I thought I'd point out that if you are planning to use this for small caps gloss abbreviations, you might want to look at the [`leipzig`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/leipzig?lang=en) package, which defines macros that would put your abbreviations in small caps but not the rest of your gloss line.

Comment: @JasonZentz Thank you, that's great!  I wasn't going to use this for functional glosses (since, as you noted the whole line would be small caps) but I'm actually working on a script to get my ELAN data into LaTeX and since I'm using Leipzig conventions anyways this could be the "missing link" that I didn't know existed — so your comment is a very welcome suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Warning: The linguistic example is wrong (I am no Linguist), but the `everyglb={\scshape}` command is working.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}

\defineglwlevels{cat,gloss}
\lingset{everyglb={\scshape},everyglcat=\footnotesize,aboveglcatskip=-.5ex}
\ex
\begingl
\gla k- wapm -a -s’i -m -wapunin -uk //
\glb Foo Stuff //
\glcat Cl V Agr Neg Agr Tns Agr //
\glgloss 2 see 3{\sc acc} {} {2\sc pl} preterit {3\sc pl} //
\glft ‘you (pl) didn’t see them’//
\endgl
\xe
\end{document}
```

Note: The example is 'stolen' from the `expex` manual ;-)